# Code with CodeIgniter on one page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't really know how to organize my code in a CodeIgniter project.
In a view, I have a form which allows after submit to have information. But the information is display on the same view. The information is displayed in multiple ways (like with PHP or with Ajax and JSON encoding in the controller part).

My view :

```
<form action="#" method="post">
 <p>Your name : <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="OK"></p>
</form>
```

What I want to display after the click on the submit button :

```
<select class="mylist">
    <?php foreach($groups as $each){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $each->groupname; ?>"><?php echo $each->groupname; ?></option>';
    <?php } ?>
</select>

      <table id="table" class="display" style="width:80%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>SurName</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr> 
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>SurName</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view("myview.php");
}

public function getlist
{
    $this->load->model('mymodel');
// Method to get the values of the list in the database

}
public function get_test_datatables()
{
// Method to fill the datatable part
echo json_encode($output);
}
```

JS Functions :

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table').DataTable({
//Get the data with ajax
})

)}
```

After I press the submit button, I also want to check if a checkbox is checked (if it equal to true in the database, I have to check the box, if it is equal to false, I don't have to check it). Have I to do something like that in the view:

```
if(checkbox->value == true)
{
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" checked> I have a bike<br>
}
else {
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

View

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="frmsubmit">
    <p>Your name : <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="OK"></p>
</form>

<select class="mylist">
    <?php foreach($groups as $each){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $each->groupname; ?>"><?php echo $each->groupname; ?></option>';
    <?php } ?>
</select>

<table id="table" class="display" style="width:80%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>SurName</th>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr> 
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>SurName</th>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready( function () {

 loaddata();

 $('#frmsubmit').on('submit', function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            url:$(this).attr('action'),
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                loaddata();
            }
        });
    });


 function loaddata()
 {
    $('#table').DataTable({
       "ajax": '<?= site_url('url') ?>'
    });
 }
});
```

database code is in models and methods are in controller.

Comment: I have a question about this part : "data:$(this).serialize()" : you pass the value of the input form ? I can't do the same thing with a post in the view : "if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {// the code I want to to show after submit}" ?
And how can I organise the code for the checkbox part ?